# Why getting char by 'ref' from string is not allowed?

Tags: c#, ref, .net-6.0

I'm curious, why this one works...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ReadOnlySpan<char> text = "Hello";
    ref readonly char c = ref text[0];
}
```

...but this one not allowed?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "Hello";
    // Error CS8156 An expression cannot be used in this context because it may not be passed or returned by reference
    ref readonly char c = ref text[0];
}
```

Is there any hidden technical reason for that limitation or something? Why C# doesn't support that? (yet?)

Comment: Technically, because a string is not an array. You're calling [the indexer](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.cs,767), which is a method that returns a `char` and not a `ref char`.

Comment: I'm wondering what benefit you perceive there to be in obtaining a `ref readonly char` in the first place. It's certainly not going to cut any overhead in invoking methods/lambdas etc over just passing a plain `char` (no `ref`).

Comment: Right, but that `ReadOnlySpan<T>` indexer returns a `ref readonly T`, and string's indexer returns a `char`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, because string's indexer [returns a `char`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.cs,767), whereas `ReadOnlySpan<T>`'s indexer [returns a `ref readonly T`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ReadOnlySpan.cs,128).

One reason for this is that `ref readonly` returns were only added to the language [in C# 7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns), the same version which introduced `ReadOnlySpan<T>`. However, `string` has been in the language since C# 1. It would be a breaking change to alter what string's indexer returns, to make it return a `ref readonly char` instead of a `char`.

More practically, returning a ref to a `char` is pretty pointless: the ref takes up more memory than the char itself! You would normally want to use `readonly ref`s when you have a large struct, and you want to access elements of it without copying the entire thing. So `ref readonly SomeLargeStruct x = ref someReadOnlySpanOfSomeLargeStruct[0]`.

Comment: I'm not sure that `the ref takes up more memory` is correct because both takes one CPU 32 or 64 register to operate, in case of local variable operations. But my main question was generally about possible .NET API gap, then you answered. Thank you!

Comment: It depends. In a register yes, but if you have two fields next to each other in a class/struct, or an array of them, the space usage will be smaller